# Solve $\log_{10}(5x)-\log_{10}(x-4)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The question is under the topic of 'Solving Logarithmic Equations'. Prior to this topic, I learnt about the Laws of Logarithm: Multiplication Law, Division Law and Power Law.

So far, I've used the Division Law $\left(\log_a(\frac{x}{y})\right)=\log_ax-\log_ay\;$ in order to get: $$\log_{10}(\frac{5x}{x-4})=1$$

I don't know how on from here since I'm stumped on what to do with $\left(\frac{5x}{x-4}\right)$

Comment: Raise both sides to power of 10, that is, take antilog and solve

Comment: I see, but what does antilog mean?

Comment: You have a logarithmic equation: $\log_a( x)=y$. Use the definition of logarithm to convert it to the equivalent exponential form: $a^y=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Raise both side to power 10 and you will get the equation

$\frac{5x}{x-4}=10$

Comment: Ah, it seems that I forgot to do that :facepalm: 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have$$\log_{10}\left(\frac{5x}{x-4}\right)=1\iff\frac{5x}{x-4}=10\iff x=8.$$